# JQuery not executing PHP in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-chrome

I am trying to get the PHP result from a call to JQuery's post method in the environment of a chrome extension. Unfortunately, all I got is the unexecuted PHP code.

Here's my call to post method :

```
$.post(chrome.extension.getURL('get_image.php'), { username: 'user' }, function(result) { 
   console.log(result); 
});
```

And my get_image.php :

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['username'];
echo $username;
exit();

?>
```

And there is the result :

[Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UzRY.png)

Thank you for your time !

Comment: what url generated by this`chrome.extension.getURL('get_image.php')`? it seems that php is not installed at the location  where this php page exist

Comment: Web browsers do not interpret php. You need to host the php on a web accessible server and pass a url to the javascript function

Comment: The url generated links to my extension's files, and indeed php is not installed there ! Trying to work this out, thank you.

Comment: Why are you using `chrome.extension.getURL` to get data from an php server? Currently you get the file contents of `get_image.php` , because there is no server behind an `chrome.extension` that will run php scripts!. Just use `'get_image.php'` to get the data from the server, not from the client.

Comment: You will need an real php server  and then you can do this on client side http://consle.com/instance/examples/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, I couldn't expect any answer from a location where PHP cannot be interpreted (in this case `chrome.extension.getURL('get_image.php')` ).
To fix this, the php file needs to be hosted on a server where php can be run.
Thank you !